# How do I get a value from HTML with multiple classes with same name?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

ow do I get the value of "Feb 2015" from HTML below? The problem I'm facing is there can be multiple "col-lg-4 col-md-6" classes or just a single one, depending on how much information a user provides about themselves:

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <dl>
                    <dt>Resident Since</dt>
                    <dd>Mar 2013</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Hometown</dt>
                        <dd>New York</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Occupation</dt>
                        <dd>Builder</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <dl>
                    <dt>Joined</dt>
                    <dd>Feb 2015</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this. If you want to find the `xpath` based on the what you have in `dt`, since that makes sure that a *`joined date`* then do the following `xpath`

```
//div[@class='col-lg-4 col-md-6']//dt[.='Joined']/../dd
```

Or, if it is always the last child you can use the following `css`

```
.col-lg-4.col-md-6:last-child dd
```

Comment: Thanks Saifur. Let me check this out and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I really gotta learn this xPath stuff ... or I can just keep coming back here and asking you! ;-)

Comment: that's the way everyone learns @ratsstack There is no special magic